# Keep a customer Anonymous - Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have created a module in Magento which takes certain views from customers about any product and displays them as extra information under each product when its approved by the admin from back end.

Now I have got three fields Name, Email N Views. I would like to know how to keep a customer anonymous in this form if he wishes not to display his name when his views are approved and posted on the product page.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a custom module? Can you not just add an extra field with their preference and then use this when you display it? I don't entirely follow what the problem is...

Comment: Yes this is a custom module. Can you elaborate on the use of extra field? Coz that's what some thing I am unsure of how to do? I was thinking of using a checkbox which if checked, the name shud remain anonymous else not. But I don't know how to pass this checkbox value every time for displaying that user's views?

Comment: Well if you've built the module you must know how to save and retrieve the data. Then you just need to do something like `if($checkbnox_field){}else{}`. I'm still not sure what it is that you're struggling with, you clearly have the required skills if you've built the module.

Comment: I have created an entire form. I can save its data in a custom database table made for this module. Edit and show it in a grid from backend. N accordingly show those posts on frontend as well. But what I would like to know is that how should I save each user's preference (i.e. if they check the checkbox) if they want to stay anonymous or not. Like when I am going to display their posts by fetching data from the database, how to know that this user had preferred to stay anonymous by checking the checkbox n his name should not b displayed.Is there a way of saving his preference in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by stumbling upon original core files. I added a checkbox in the form on the front end.

```
<li class="control"><input type="checkbox" name="is_anonymous" id="anonymous" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Is Anonymous') ?>"<?php if($this->getIsAnonymous()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" /><label for="anonymous"><?php echo $this->__('Is Anonymous') ?></label></li>
```

I added the `is_anonymous` column in the table and in the core controller file I added this to save the preference of each user

```
 if($post = $this->getRequest()->getParam('is_anonymous'))
 { $record->setIsAnonymous(1); 
 else
 { $record->setIsAnonymous(0); }
```

And then to display it on front end I added an extra condition in list.phtml

```
<small class="by"><?php echo $this->__('By: '); ?><?php if($entry->getIsAnonymous()==1) {echo 'Anonymous';} else { echo $entry->getName();} ?></small>
```

And this lets me have a check box which if ticked displays the post as 'Anonymous' by user who has posted or else displays his name on the front end.

Hope this helps some one!